# How to resolve the issue with Nan error in pmap_dbl with average in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, nan, mean, purrr

I'm trying to calculate (for testing purposes) a mean with pmap_dbl (purrr package) and I get back NaN. Shouldn't the result be numeric, when I pass the argument na.rm=TRUE?
What puzzles me is that with sum function this works ok.

```
library(tidyverse)

airquality%>%select(Ozone,Wind,Temp, Month, Day)%>%
  filter(is.na(Ozone))%>%
  mutate(Something=pmap_dbl(list(Ozone,Wind,Temp,Month,Day),mean,na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  head(3)%>%as_tibble()

 Ozone  Wind  Temp Month   Day Something
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1    NA  14.3    56     5     5       NaN
2    NA   8.6    69     5    10       NaN
3    NA  16.6    57     5    25       NaN

  airquality%>%select(Ozone,Wind,Temp, Month, Day)%>%
  filter(is.na(Ozone))%>%
  mutate(Something=pmap_dbl(list(Ozone,Wind,Temp,Month,Day),sum,na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  head(3)%>%as_tibble()


  Ozone  Wind  Temp Month   Day Something
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1    NA  14.3    56     5     5      80.3
2    NA   8.6    69     5    10      92.6
3    NA  16.6    57     5    25     104.
```

Comment: What is `something` supposed to be? The `mean` of Ozone, Wind, Temp, Month and Day?

Comment: Yes, I am just testing the pmap_dbl function with some corner cases. What confuses me is that the sum function works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `mean()` accepts only a single vector of values but `pmap()` passes each individually (in this case really vectors of length 1) so to get it to work they need to be concatenated first.  In your attempt `mean()` was performed only on the first value passed (the `NA`) and the other values are treated as other arguments to the function so in this case effectively ignored, and the result is `NaN`. `sum()` on the other hand can take any number of vectors passed individually which is why it worked but `mean()` did not.

```
airquality %>%
  select(Ozone, Wind, Temp, Month, Day) %>%
  filter(is.na(Ozone)) %>%
  mutate(Something = pmap_dbl(list(Ozone, Wind, Temp, Month, Day), function(...)
    mean(c(...), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  head(3) %>% 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Ozone  Wind  Temp Month   Day Something
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1    NA  14.3    56     5     5      20.1
2    NA   8.6    69     5    10      23.2
3    NA  16.6    57     5    25      25.9
```